# d3 selectors: Works in code but not in console. Why?

Tags: javascript, firebug, d3.js

Using d3, I can:

```
var labels = d3.select("div#labels").insert("svg:svg")
  //....
```

Then, below in the code I can do:

```
labels.selectAll("text")
  //... act upon the selection...
```

But in the firebug console:

```
>>> labels.selectAll("text")
  // produces: TypeError: labels.select is not a function
```

And:

```
>>> d3.labels.selectAll("text")
  //produces: TypeError: d3.labels is undefined
```

Why?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I would assume the answer is "scope".  `labels` is simply defined in a smaller scope, that no longer exists once you reach the Firebug console.

Comment: More code, please. What's the context you're calling the function from?

Comment: You have an element with ID `labels`. At the console, `labels` refers to the global variable `labels` which is the DOM element with ID labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have two different `labels` variables. A local and a global one.

At the place where you declare the local `var labels`, also store it in the global scope for debugging (e.g., via `window.locallabels = labels`). Then in the console test if your different labels are the same. I guess they are not.

```
var labels = { text: "bla" }     // create a new object

function fn(){
    var labels = { text: "bla" } // create another object
    window.locallabels = labels  // save it in global scope for debugging
}

fn();

console.log(labels, locallabels, labels == locallabels) //try this in console
//console: Object { text="bla"} Object { text="bla"} false
```

Comment: I guess you can only select things using selectors, not variable names that are no longer in scope.  I had not used `attr("id", "labels")` on the d3 method chain in the code, but once I did I was able to pull it up in the console with `>>>d3.select('#labels')` I guess it's a case of selecting a DOM element vs. a local variable that is destroyed when it's no longer in context.  Thanks for the answer and time.